# Extract specific strings from file

Tags: bash

Good morning guys,
I'm trying to extract from this [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1heO1jvWD11nkMajNzuAbKQ5BgPvcFy4D)

I have necessary extract only alls links with pattern '/9.4.10/':

> grep "/9.4.10/" test.txt

After this command i have see all links

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: grep returns a matching line. In your file you have 14 lines according to `cat test.txt | wc -l `, so grep is not the tool you want, as one matching will return the whole huge line.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe help to pull out all the links, and then grep.

Try it:

```
cat test.txt | grep -Eo "(http|https)://[\da-z./?A-Z0-9\D=_-]*" | grep "\/9.4.10\/"
```